# Over Amplitute Modulation vs DSB_SC Modulation

Tags: modulation, amplitude-modulation

What is the difference between over AM and DSB_SC modulation. When I look the modulated signal waves, it confuces me.If we look the below figure and if we don't have an information about modulation type, how can we know its type? That is, How do we know if the wave is over AM or DSB-SC if we don't have any information?
[image: Over Am or DSB-SC ?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four-quadrant multiplier yielding double-sideband suppressed-carrier that Andy's answer mentions might produce a similar-looking wave shape that you included in your question. (Thank you for including it).
...**However**...
When the low-frequency modulating signal (in green) passes through zero, the carrier undergoes a 180 degree phase inversion. The signal below is DSB, (with phase inversions), while yours appears to have no phase inversion.
[image: DSB-SC]

If you applied this waveform to a 4-quadrant multiplying demodulator, you'd get a very different baseband signal out. The phase inversions of the carrier wave may be hard to spot visually on an oscilloscope, especially when the carrier frequency is so very much higher than the modulating base band signal.
[image: another attempt to show carrier phase & DSBSC]

Comment: I don't think there is enough detail in the original picture to say that the carrier **doesn't** invert when the modulating signal changes polarity. I've looked hard at it and some transitions look like they invert and some don't. My guess is that some prof drew it and it got copied a couple of times and precise detail got messed with like [Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Whispers). OK it's called the "telephone game" by all the holy political correctites of the world.

Comment: @Andyaka I'd agree, and I'm likely guilty of adding to the pixel confusion with my attempt at editing the OP's image. The original image *does appear* to have some phase discontinuity at zero crossings, but I'd judge it is not near 180 degrees.

Comment: Then, can I say that it is occured phase reversal in DSBS-SC?

Comment: jasmin...that image is **another case** of ambiguous phase reversal!  Am adding another attempt at a DSBSC wave to my answer that might make it more clear. Compare carefully the time relationship between the square-wave carrier phase reference (purple) to the modulated carrier (green). Try clicking on that image to make it bigger.

Answer (score 1):

If the picture shown in your diagram is all the information you have, then you cannot be sure whether the waveform is true DSBSC with a sinewave modulation sitting on top of some slow moving waveform OR, it's an over modulated non-suppressed carrier AM signal.

You could make guesses, but, why would you?

What you can ask yourself is this:

> **Why would somebody go to the trouble of building a 4-quadrant analogue
> multiplier (aka DSBSC modulator) when the only type of modulator
> needed is 2-quadrant i.e. one that is suitable for broadcast type AM**

I'm posing that question because if you over-modulated a 2-quadrant multiplier you would get modulating signal clipping at 0 volts if it tried to go below 0 volts rather than the waveform shown. That's the only clue that might tell you that the circuit is truly a 4-quadrant multiplier capable of DSBSC.

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I understood what you told me. But I also wonder, what is the difference in the occurrence of ovar AM and DSB-SC modulation? So, negative alternans in both seem to be inverted.

Comment: @jasmin I don't think I understand your comment i.e. "difference in the occurrence". Do you mean how common is one compared to the other in terms of real-world usage?

Comment: No, I mean that the negative alternans seems to inverted in both of them. For example, In the osiloscope, I have a sinus signal. Then the teacher wants from me, make the sinus signal DSBSC. Then, how I can know, if I make it over modulation or DSBSC ?

Comment: @jasmin I don't understand what you mean. I don't know what you mean by "alternans" and I'm struggling to see anything that appears to be inverted. "make the sinus signal DSBSC" also doesn't make sense because DSBSC cannot be a sinus signal ever - for it to exist with any non-zero amplitude it has to be modulated and that means it isn't sinus shaped. Sorry. I think we have a translation problem.